# T-SQL query to check historical data of table or resources being locked

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are few T-SQL Jobs which are moving data from one table to other. The jobs fail because of timeout sometimes. I identified that there is no much data to process and suspect that the underlying tables might be blocked by someone else. I want a query to find out the historical records of resources (tables etc) being locked by any other process/stored proc.

I have searched online portals but most of them give me the query to find out the resources locked currently and not the historical ones. Since the jobs are running and failing during night time, I want to see what happened, in the morning.

Comment: Unless you are recording the current data (trace logs, recurring snapshot processes, third party monitoring tool, etc), SQL Server does not maintain historical data such as you're seeking.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but take a peak at Dynamic Management Views.  You can get some good usage info that might lead you to what you are looking for, but I don't think deadlock info.   Aside from that you'll need to run profiler during a window of time where you expect problems and/or be looking at activity monitor.

Answer (score 1):

For recent deadlocks, there's [sp_BlitzLock](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/introducing-sp_blitzlock-troubleshooting-sql-server-deadlocks/) (part of [Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit](http://FirstResponderKit.org)).

Just execute it without parameters and it shows a table with recent deadlocks, including the exact queries that caused the deadlocks.